# Pandas dataframe update column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframes:

```
>>> df1
  Col1 Col2       Col3
0    A    a 2017-02-28
1    B    b 2017-02-28
2    C    c 2017-03-08
3    D    d 2017-02-28

>>> df2
  Col1 Col2       Col3
0    B    b 2017-03-05
1    C    c 2017-03-05
2    D    d 2017-03-05
```

and I want to update `df1.Col3` with the data of `df2.Col3` when the date of `df2.Col3` is the more recent to have the answer:

```
>>> df1
  Col1 Col2       Col3
0    A    a 2017-02-28
1    B    b 2017-03-05
2    C    c 2017-03-08
3    D    d 2017-03-05
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are used to using R.  The syntax to select a column in Pandas is either `df.Col1` or `df['Col1']`.

You can concatenate the two dataframe, sort by `Col3`, then drop the duplicates of the combination of `['Col1','Col2']`.  You need to convert `Col3` to datetime objects if you haven't already.

```
> df1.Col3 = pd.to_datetime(df1.Col3)
> df2.Col3 = pd.to_datetime(df2.Col3)
> (pd.concat((df1, df2))
      .reset_index(drop=True)
      .sort_values('Col3')
      .drop_duplicates(['Col1','Col2'], keep='last'))

#returns:
  Col1 Col2       Col3
0    A    a 2017-02-28
4    B    b 2017-03-05
6    D    d 2017-03-05
2    C    c 2017-03-08
```